# Not able to increase size of box after 1296 [screen resolution]. is there any solution for this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

**Not able to increase size of box after 1296[screen resolution]. is there any solution for this?**

1. i am using WndProc method for changing cursor and moving it on picture box.
2. After setting cursor painting the rectangle using paint method.

**It will Draw the Rectangle **

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Black, 4))
            {
                p.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
            }
            clsCommon.SelectedImageHeight = Height;
            clsCommon.SelectedImageWidth = Width;
        }
```

**It will change the cursor **

```
const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
        const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x20;
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0xA3;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            string Msg = "";
            int borderWidth = 10;
            if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR)  /*Setting cursor to SizeAll*/
            {
                if ((m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff) == 0x2 /*Move*/)
                {
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.SizeAll;
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                    return;
                }
            }
            if ((m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)) /*Disable Mazimiz on Double click*/
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            {
                var pos = PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16));
                if (pos.X <= ClientRectangle.Left + borderWidth && pos.Y <= ClientRectangle.Top + borderWidth)
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(13); //TOPLEFT
                else if (pos.X >= ClientRectangle.Right - borderWidth && pos.Y <= ClientRectangle.Top + borderWidth)
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(14); //TOPRIGHT
                else if (pos.X <= ClientRectangle.Left + borderWidth && pos.Y >= ClientRectangle.Bottom - borderWidth)
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(16); //BOTTOMLEFT
                else if (pos.X >= ClientRectangle.Right - borderWidth && pos.Y >= ClientRectangle.Bottom - borderWidth)
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(17); //BOTTOMRIGHT
                else if (pos.X <= ClientRectangle.Left + borderWidth)
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(10); //LEFT
                else if (pos.Y <= ClientRectangle.Top + borderWidth)
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(12); //TOP
                else if (pos.X >= ClientRectangle.Right - borderWidth)
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(11); //RIGHT
                else if (pos.Y >= ClientRectangle.Bottom - borderWidth)
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(15); //Bottom
                else
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(2); //Move

                //frmcoding.DispMsg("pos.X : " + pos.X + " pos.Y : " + pos.Y);
            }

            
        }
```

Comment: @Reza Aghaei you have any solution on this?

Comment: This is definitely not asp.net related... you can't do stuff like this in web apps.

Comment: @Nyerguds It is windows application related.